# Why is the colors on my React Native App (Expo) different than the pantone app?

Tags: react-native, background-color, pantone

I want to pair the colors but I got them wrong

So the same #00AFDB seems pale or off in the expo app 
[image: An image says more than 1000 words]

Comment: Same here - did you find out what was happening?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Maybe the JS engine/compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Are you comparing based on swipeable app views? If yes than the background apps are darker for the provided effect than the one on the foreground.

Comment: Yes I know, but it is not only that. It appears lots different. Changing from one app to the other. All the colors are a lot off on React Native.